# Using a returned value from one class function to another [Python]

Tags: python, return, nltk

I was working on a project with Python NLTK and had some issues with the `joiner()` function being unable to retrieve a return value from another function within the same class, named `open_file()`. Was wondering how exactly the return function should work in this context and how I can fix this. Thanks everyone!

Code:

```
import nltk

nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


class Sentence:

    def open_file(self):
        file_vals = []
        i = 0
        with open("words.txt", "r") as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
                if i < 20:
                    stripped_line = line.strip()
                    file_vals.append(stripped_line)
                    i += 1
                else:
                    print(file_vals)
                    return file_vals

    def joiner(self, file_vals):
        val_1 = wn.synsets(file_vals[0])[0].pos()
        val_2 = wn.synsets(file_vals[1])[0].pos()

        if val_1 == "n" and val_2 == "v":
            print(val_1.capitalize() + " " + val_2 + ".")


my_obj = Sentence()
my_obj.open_file()
my_obj.joiner()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that you did not include the error message.
However, the apparent problem with your code is that methods defined in a class do not execute until the class is instantiated and the method called. This is why you cannot pass a value from one method to another inside an un-instantiated class. One way to achieve what I believe you want to do is:
This is assuming that all other parts of your code do not contain errors. Also, I did not try to run your code.

```
import nltk

nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


class Sentence:

    def open_file(self):
        file_vals = []
        i = 0
        with open("words.txt", "r") as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
                if i < 20:
                    stripped_line = line.strip()
                    file_vals.append(stripped_line)
                    i += 1
                else:
                    print(file_vals)
                    return file_vals

    def joiner(self, file_vals):
        val_1 = wn.synsets(file_vals[0])[0].pos()
        val_2 = wn.synsets(file_vals[1])[0].pos()

        if val_1 == "n" and val_2 == "v":
            print(val_1.capitalize() + " " + val_2 + ".")

my_obj = Sentence()
file_vals = my_obj.open_file()
my_obj.joiner(file_vals)
```

You have to first save the value returned by the 'open_file' method and then pass the returned value to 'joiner' as an argument.

Comment: Ah yes the error message is as follows: "TypeError: joiner() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file_vals'". I tried running the solution code and unfortunately the same issue occurs.

Comment: I guess this is because the name ``` file_vals``` is the same as in the function definition. This should work:

```
my_obj = Sentence()
file_values = my_obj.open_file()
my_obj.joiner(file_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you calling `joiner()` function is incorrect. Since the `open_file()` fucntion return variable `file_vals` and `joiner()` function as you defined is required `file_vals` as its argument, so you should pass the return result of `open_file()` function to `joiner()` function, for example:

```
my_obj = Sentence()
my_obj.joiner(my_obj.open_file())
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to resolve the return issue. Seems like I still have an issue with val_2 which is "IndexError: list index out of range", any ideas on that?

Comment: It should be because of  `file_vals[1]`. there is no value at index `1` of `file_vals` in some cases.

Comment: Oddly enough, the printed list shows a value at both index 0 and 1 all the way through 19, still not entirely sure why the out of range error is being thrown.